# How to make time delay in for loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, sleep

I want to display multiple records in windows form having 2 seconds delay after each record is displayed. i am trying Thread.Sleep(2000) but it is not working. I am writing following code

```
for (var j = 0; j < connectionGetRecord.DataSet.Tables["StudentTable"].Rows.Count; j++)
{
    labelName.Text = connectionGetRecord.DataSet.Tables["StudentTable"].Rows[j]["Name"].ToString();
    labelFatherName.Text = connectionGetRecord.DataSet.Tables["StudentTable"].Rows[j]["FatherName"].ToString();
    labelRollNumber.Text = connectionGetRecord.DataSet.Tables["StudentTable"].Rows[j]["RollNumber"].ToString();
    var image = (byte[])connectionGetRecord.DataSet.Tables["StudentTable"].Rows[j]["Image"];
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(stream);
    var classId = (int)connectionGetRecord.DataSet.Tables["StudentTable"].Rows[j]["ClassId"];
    command.CommandText = "Select ClassName From TBLCLasses where ClassId=@ClassId";
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassId", classId);
    connectionGetRecord.GetRecord("TBLClasses", command);
    labelClass.Text = connectionGetRecord.DataSet.Tables["TBLClasses"].Rows[0]["ClassName"].ToString();
    pictureBox1.Size = new Size(530, 540);
    //command.CommandText = "Update TblStudent set PCDT=@PCDT where StudentId=@StudentId";
    //command.Parameters.Clear();
    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCDT", DateTime.Now);
    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentId", textBoxComputerNUmber.Text);
    //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Dispose();
    connectionGetRecord.connection.Close();
    path = connectionGetRecord.DataSet.Tables["StudentTable"].Rows[j]["Path"].ToString();
    //Flash(labelName, 1000, Color.Black, 10);
    // Flash(labelClass, 1000, Color.Black, 10);
    player.SoundLocation = path;
    player.Play();
    Thread.Sleep(2000); 
}
```

I have multiple records against driver id and i want to display them one by one with 2 seconds of time interval between each record displayed.Problem with this code i am having is that i get displayed only the last record of dataset table. I want every record to be displayed with 2 seconds of time interval.

Also i want to play sound for each record as written in my code.Each recording is also of 2 seconds.Can anyone please tell  me what i am doing wrong?Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly "is not working"?

Comment: I guess what you mean by "not working" is that your UI doesn't get updated. The proper solution would be to use a BackgroundWorker, INotifyPropertyChanged and DataBinding. A "DoEvents" call will do the trick also, but I'm not going to give that code to you, as it's actively harmful.

Comment: @shay if you're trying to be funny: you're not supposed to post an _answer_ in which you guess the problem when the problem is not clear, that is why I commented _"Don't guess"_ under your answer. If a question is unclear, you use comments to ask for clarification (just like I did above); then once the problem is clear, you can post an answer. _"This line looks like a bug"_ is a guess and not an answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster I did ask for clarification, one comment above you. Yet, I'm sure you'll agree, that closing the connection inside a loop is a sure bug. TMO, your comment was uncalled for, but let's not argue about it. I will remove my teasing comments.

Comment: @shay you did, but you [also posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31857262/266143). The comment is fine, the answer not. If OP doesn't want to explain what the actual problem is, flag to close the question as being "Unclear what you're asking". I can easily list ten potential problems with this code, but that's hardly helpful in an answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster i have edited my question with the problem i am getting please read

Comment: @bunny yeah so my guess was correct, your UI doesn't get updated until after this loop has completed. See my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857165/how-to-make-time-delay-in-for-loop#comment51633962_31857165).

Comment: why you guys are fighting? :(

Comment: @shay__ yes you are right please give me answer now

Comment: waiting for the answer :(

Comment: Your answer is in [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857165/how-to-make-time-delay-in-for-loop/31857262#comment51633962_31857165).

Answer (score 0):

As The Play() function of the SoundPlayer creates a separate thread, you should rather use the PlaySync() function, if you want to wait until the end of current record before playing the next one.